# Regex to select multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have a text file with multiple lines. There are no paragraphs only lines.

I need to write a regex to select multiple lines.

Example.

```
Quick Black Fox
Jumps over the lazy 
dog
```

I need to search for 'over'. If 'over' is found, I have to select from 'Quick' to 'dog'. Is this possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `(?s)` DOTALL modifier to make dot to match newline characters.

```
(?s)Quick.*?over.*?dog
```

OR

Add word boundary `\b` if necessary. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
(?s)\bQuick\b.*?\bover\b.*?\bdog\b
```

OR

If you're running javascript, `[\s\S]*?` matches any character including line breaks. Note that there isn't a dotall modifier `s` in js.

```
\bQuick\b[\s\S]*?\bover\b[\s\S]*?\bdog\b
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/9)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it if you use a language like JavaScript, which does not have the **s** modifier:

```
(.|\n)*over(.|\n)*
```

Here it is in action: https://regex101.com/r/oH9cH7/2

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*/s
```

The s at the back notes regex to match new lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way

```
Quick\(.\|\n\)*? over \(.\|\n\)*
```